# Magento2: Get Media URL In Template File (Without direct Calling Object Manager )

Tags: magento2, template, magento-2.1, media, object-manager

How to Get `Media URL` in Template file ? 
All the solution i found is calling Object Manager directly.
My another concern, Can you ever call object manager directly as best practice ? (because in most of the solution they are using object manager)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can get media url in your template file using below way but without using objectmanager you must have to define Block file with `__construct()` method with define **storeManagerInterface** in construct method.

In your phtml Block file create `__construct` function.

**public $_storeManager;**

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
{
       $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

In your phtml file call below method to get media url:

```
$mediaUrl = $this ->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
```

**echo $mediaUrl;**

This is the proper way to get media url in Magento 2.

Comment: I reckon it would be way better to make that variable protected and create a getter method to retrieve the media url instead

Comment: If your block extends from `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`, you already have an instance of `StoreManagerInterface` (`$this->_storeManager`).

Comment: I got media url . But i need to display the image corresponding to that url...If you know help me to sort out my problem. Please refer the below link        https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201961/how-to-fetch-the-image-from-db-and-display-it-to-frontend-in-magento-2

Answer (score 15):

As of 2.1, there is no direct way of getting the media URL without either:

- calling the object manager directly (please don't do that)
- override the block and add a new method

Rakesh mentioned one way of doing it.

Another way is to use the protected variable `$_urlBuilder` which is included for every block as defined in the `AbstractBlock` : https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/f2d309a88298886460351c04973a4ff95c7a91c0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php#L186

Thus you don't have to modify the constructor of your block and can simply add the following method:

```
public function getMediaUrl() {
    return $this->_urlBuilder->getBaseUrl(['_type' => UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA]);
}
```

Then in your template you can call:

```
$block->getMediaUrl();
```

Comment: i think it's absurd that i can't just retrieve media path in .phtml directly.

Comment: @LucScu it might be discouraged, for sure. Probably not the best idea to reference an asset that has been uploaded and is not part of the codebase. It feels a bit nasty doing so.

Comment: @LucScu it is absurd. Just use the object manager. There is no benefit of using the convoluted 'best' way just to get a url... This is the real world not 'best practice' world.  'Best practices' that Magento doesn't even follow lol. My goodness Magento really is trash I hate it so much 

Comment: @00-BBB thats actually a wrong statement. Magento2 uses a lot of modern code styles, keeps many aspects in respect, whatsoever. Using of the Object Manager is by far the worst idea one can make - and besides that, the real coding world perfectly fits into "best practice"-approaches, if handled properly. That said, Magento2 overall is still not good - but for a lot of other reasons.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to go to the trouble of extending \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template, and you want your .phtml file to use the block \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template, then you can use this shortcut:

```
$this->helper('Magento\Cms\Helper\Wysiwyg\Images')->getBaseUrl()
```

Comment: Using $this->helper() in PHTML files is deprecated and discouraged

Answer (score 5):

**Edit: Please note that this was a valid and documented answer when first answered, but helpers have since now been deprecated, and so the use of the below is highly discouraged.**

---

I'm going to use Raphael's answer and extend it - but instead of adding the method into the block class, why not create a helper and add it in there?

Start by creating a new module the usual way, and within the root, create a new folder called "Helper" and add the required code in there:

```php
namespace YourSite\YourModule\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
class Url extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function getMediaPath() {
        return $this->_urlBuilder->getBaseUrl(['_type' => UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA]);
    }

}
```

Once activated and compiled, you will be able to use it within your template file using the following method:

```php
<?php $url = $this->helper('\YourSite\YourModule\Helper\Url'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $url->getMediaPath() ?>wysiwyg/image.jpg" />
```

I hope you (and potentially others) find this of great use!

Comment: Using $this->helper() in PHTML files is deprecated and discouraged

Answer (score 4):

At least in 2.2.6, you can use `Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::getDirectUrl()`

```php
    protected function buildMediaUrl($path)
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getDirectUrl( $path, ['_type' => UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA]);
    }
```

Comment: With some small adaptions this should be the accepted answer as of today. For several reasons: it takes in a parameter (`path`) to build the full URL rather than having the Developer to concat a string ugly in the Phtml, its a method that should be implemented in a Block, ... By far the best answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You Try this for product Image

```
$this->helper('Magento\Cms\Helper\Wysiwyg\Images')->getBaseUrl().'catalog/product'.$_product->getImage();
```

Comment: Call to helper in template file is deprecated

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar you write this many places. Maybe you could suggest the "corret" way to do it as well?

Comment: @william Please refer to the accepted answer or top two answer to check the correct way

Answer (score 0):

To get the media URL in a template file in Magento 2 without directly calling the Object Manager, you can follow these steps:

1. Inject the `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` class into your block class constructor. Open the block class file (e.g., `CustomBlock.php`).

```php
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    // ...
}
```

2. Create a public function in the block class to retrieve the media URL. Add the following code to the `CustomBlock.php` file:

```php
public function getMediaUrl($file)
{
    $mediaUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    return $mediaUrl . $file;
}
```

3. In your template file (e.g., `custom_template.phtml`), you can now call the `getMediaUrl` function and pass the file path as a parameter to get the complete media URL.

```html
<img src="<?php echo $block->getMediaUrl('catalog/product/image.jpg'); ?>" alt="Product Image">
```

By following these steps, you can retrieve the media URL in a template file without directly calling the Object Manager in Magento 2.