# how to display images stored in pub/media folder

Tags: image, media-images

hello everyone I want to display an image from the folder "pub/media" and concatinate it with my path from the image field from database but I can't display it in detail page with the ways that I have tested

can anyone help me please

> this is what I have done with 2 ways

method 1

```
<p><?php echo __('image') ?>: <img src="<?= $user->getImg() ?>" alt="image" /></p>
```

method 2

```
$pathmedia = "pub/media";
<img src="<?php echo $block->getUrl($pathmedia."/".$user->getImg())?>"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getUrl('pub/media').$user->getImg(); ?>" />
```

Hoping this will contain path of image coming form database.

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

love coding.

Have you tried this approach?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/133009/92898

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/184719)

Comment: It makes sense, @sandip.